# Select by id and generate column with relationships in array

Tags: postgresql

Essentially what i want to do is to get by id from "Tracks" but i also want to get the relations it has to other tracks (found in table "Remixes").

I can write a simple query that gets the track i want by id, ex.

```
SELECT * FROM "Tracks" WHERE id IN ('track-id1');
```

That gives me:

```
    id     |    dateModified     |    channels     | userId 
-----------+---------------------+-----------------+--------
 track-id1 | 2019-07-21 12:15:46 | {"some":"json"} |      1
```

But this is what i want to get:

```
    id     |   dateModified      |    channels     | userId | remixes
-----------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+---------
 track-id1 | 2019-07-21 12:15:46 | {"some":"json"} |      1 | track-id2, track-id3
```

So i want to generate a column called "remixes" with ids in an array based on the data that is available in the "Remixes" table by a SELECT query.

Here is example data and database structure:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ec2e6/3

Don't hesitate to ask questions in case anything is unclear,

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it

Answer (score 0):

Left join the remixes and then `GROUP BY` the track ID and use `array_agg()` to get an array of the remix IDs.

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE 
         WHEN array_agg(r."remixTrackId") = '{NULL}'::varchar(255)[] THEN
           '{}'::varchar(255)[]
         ELSE
           array_agg(r."remixTrackId")
       END "remixes"
       FROM "Tracks" t
            LEFT JOIN "Remixes" r
                      ON r."originalTrackId" = t."id"
       WHERE t."id" = 'track-id1'
       GROUP BY t."id";
```

Note that, if there are no remixes `array_agg()` will return `{NULL}`. But I figured you rather want an empty array in such a case. That's what the `CASE` is for.

BTW, providing a fiddle is a nice move of yours! But please also include the code in the original question. The fiddle site might be down (even permanently) and that renders the question useless because of the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple outer join with a string aggregation to get the comma separated list:

```
SELECT t.*,
       string_agg(r."remixTrackId", ', ') as remixes
FROM "Tracks" t
  LEFT JOIN "Remixes" r ON r."originalTrackId" = t.id
WHERE t.id = 'track-id1'
GROUP BY t.id;
```

The above assumes that `Tracks.id` is the primary key of the `Tracks` table.